# GitLab API v4 only collects less than 20 issue comments

Tags: json, gitlab

If I collect all issues within an Issue only 20 comments will be shown in the JSON string.
Reason: [Default Pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/database/pagination_guidelines.html)

If I collect all Issues within an Milestone I can use the parameter `per_page=100`.

```bash
$ key="$PRIVATE_TOKEN"
$ proj_url="https://<URL>/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID"
$ curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $key" "$proj_url/issues?milestone=<MILESTONE NAME>&per_page=100"
```

How can I collect all issue notes with GitLab API?

```bash
$ key="$PRIVATE_TOKEN"
$ proj_url="https://<URL>/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID"
$ curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $key" "$proj_url/issues/193/notes"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GitLab Notes API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#notes-pagination) confirms that, by default, `GET` requests return 20 results at a time because the API results are paginated.
But `per_page=100` should still be available for this type of query.

The other option would be to use the [GitLab CLI `glab`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/glab/) to make the same query with [`glab api`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/tree/main/docs/source/api), but with `--paginate`

> In '--paginate' mode, all pages of results will sequentially be requested until there are no more pages of results.